# What is the difference between the externalNativeBuild option inside/outside of the defaultConfig in android gradle file

Tags: android, android-ndk

I saw that the build.gradle file automatically generated when I start a new ndk project has two `externalNativeBuild` options, one inside the `defaultConfig` option and one is parallel to the `defaultConfig` option. For instance, below are the content of the gradle file I have:
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags ""
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
            version "3.10.2"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

}
```

What are the differences between them? I searched the documentation and for the insider one it says:

> Encapsulates per-variant CMake and ndk-build configurations for your
> external native build.

and for the outside one it says:

> DSL object to configure external native builds using CMake or
> ndk-build.

but for the sub option of the outside one, e.g., the cmake option, it says:

> Encapsulates per-variant configurations for your external ndk-build
> project, such as the path to your CMakeLists.txt build script and
> build output directory.

Now I am confused why there are two externalNativeBuild options, and how should I config each?

Comment: Check the documentation to see what you configure with each of them. [These](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ExternalNativeCmakeOptions.html) are the properties available in `defaultConfig { externalNativeBuild { cmake`, and [these](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.CmakeOptions.html) are the properties available in `externalNativeBuild { cmake`.

Comment: @Michael Still why we need two `externalNativeBuild` at different location, why not combine them into one?

Comment: They don't have the same scope. One is for per-variant configurations, and one is for per-module configurations.

Comment: Latest url: https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.2/com/android/build/api/variant/ExternalNativeBuild and https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.2/com/android/build/api/dsl/ExternalNativeBuild